# Angular click event: how to select a checkbox within an a element?

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, onclick, event-capturing

In my Angular app I have the following menu:

[image]

As you can see I have items (that are `a` elements) and a checkbox and a label in each of them:

```
<span class="caption">RAM</span>
<a class="item">
    <div class="item-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
        <label>4 GB</label>
    </div>
</a>
<a class="item">
    <div class="item-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
        <label>8 GB</label>
    </div>
</a>
<a class="item">
    <div class="item-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
        <label>16 GB</label>
    </div>
</a>
```

How should I add `(click)` to every item to correctly handle event capturing so if user click on label or on whole item I get the related checkbox selected?

...Or do you know a better way to reach what I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure that clicking on the label toggles the checkbox, include the input element inside of the label (as explained in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)):

```html
<a class="sub-item item">
  <div class="item-checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden">4 GB</label>
  </div>
</a>
```

If you also want the label to fill the anchor element, define the CSS  as shown below. With this styling in place, clicking on the anchor will toggle the checkbox.

```css
.ui.secondary.menu a.item {
  padding: 0px;
}

div.item-checkbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.item-checkbox > label {
  display: block;
  padding: .78571429em .92857143em;
}

div.item-checkbox > label > input {
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/semantic-ui-9huauw?file=app%2Fapp.component.css) for a demo.

Comment: This looks to be the best answer. Anyway how to extend click to the `a` element? So clicking on the `a` will toggle the checkbox. Please have a look at my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/semantic-ui-udkfhf. Thank you

Comment: I updated the answer and the stackblitz to make sure that clicking on the anchor toggles the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you can place all the checkboxes in a container, you can set a single `click` event listener on the container, and `event.target` will give you the clicked element and `previousElementSibling` will select the sibling input.

```
function doSomething() {
    const selectedInput = event.target.previousElementSibling;
    selectedInput.checked = selectedInput.checked? false : true;
}
```

But in case there is a probability that you document structure changes in the future, say for example, if other elements get in between the input and the label, or their order changes, then the sibling selector will fail. To solve this you can use a parent selector instead and select the chechbox input element inside of it.

```js
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', doSomething);

function doSomething() {
    const selectedElement = event.target.parentElement.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
    selectedElement.checked = selectedElement.checked? false:true;
}
```

```html
<div id= 'container'>
  <span class="caption">RAM</span>
  <a class="item">
      <div class="item-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden" value="4 GB">
          <label>4 GB</label>
      </div>
  </a>
  <a class="item">
      <div class="item-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden" value="8 GB">
          <label>8 GB</label>
      </div>
  </a>
  <a class="item">
      <div class="item-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden" value="16 GB">
          <label>16 GB</label>
      </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I was not clear, sorry for this. I'm talking about "event capturing". I have edited my question. In your snippet if you click on label or on whole item I don't get related checkbox selected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use *ngFor to list all your options:

**html:**

```
<a class="item" *ngFor="let choice of checks; let i=index">
    <div class="item-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden" [value]="choice.value" (change)="onCheckChange($event)">
        <label>{{choice.title}}</label>
    </div>
</a>
```

**component:**

```
public checks: Array<choices> = [
  {title: '4 GB', value: '4'},
  {title: "8 GB", value: '8'},
  {title: "16 GB", value: '16'}
];

public onCheckChange(event) {
    // do some things here
}
```

Further, you should use Reactive Forms to validate your choices:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Yes, I'm using ReactiveForms and, yes, I'm using `*ngFor`. The code in my question is just a sample... Anyway, I was not enough clear, I have edited my question. Please read it again. Thank you!

Comment: If you just want that your span is also triggering the whole checkbox, how about to use https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview?

Comment: I'm not using Material.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a boolean array and bind this to your checkboxes.

> .ts file

```
  myArray: any[] = [
 {
      "size": "2GB",
      "value":false
    },
    {
      "size": "4GB",
      "value":false
    },
    {
      "size": "8GB",
      "value":false
    }
]
```

> .html file

```
<div *ngFor="let data of myArray">
 <a class="item">
    <div class="item-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden" [(ngModel)]="data.value" (ngModelChange)="changeHandler()">
        <label>{{data.size}}</label>
    </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Working demo : [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hmmfcg)

Comment: I was not clear, sorry for this. I'm talking about "event capturing". I have edited my question. In your snippet if you click on label or on whole item I don't get related checkbox selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
const ramOptions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    size: '4 GB'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    size: '8 GB'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    size: '16 GB'
  }
]
```

And in html:

```
<a class="item" *ngFor="let option of ramOptions">
    <div class="item-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden" (change)="onSelect(option.id)">
        <label>{{option.size}}</label>
    </div>
</a>
```

If in the .js/.ts file, you can create an interface to define the handler. Just as:

```
onSelect(id: string) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I was not clear, sorry for this. I'm talking about "event capturing". I have edited my question.

Comment: You could put the function call on the <a> element